# How delete a variable number of lines

Tags: variables, vim, buffer

In a vimscript I need to delete lines from the buffer, but the number of lines will vary with each iteration of the loop.  :d is the only command I know of that will remove entire lines, but how can I use it with a variable specifying the number of lines to be deleted?

Comment: examples please. your description of problem is too abstract. what loop? what iteration?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been searching around for this solution and ended up using the `exec` command.

I used `silent!` because otherwise you'll get an error if the range doesn't exist.

```
function! DeleteLines(lineFirst, lineLast)
  silent! exec a:lineFirst . "," . a:lineLast ."d"
endfunction
```

To use the function:

`:call DeleteLines(5,10)` to delete lines 5 through 10;

`:call DeleteLines(5,'$')` to delete lines 5 through the end of the file (to illustrate quoting the end of file shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't do it directly, but achieved desired end by setting marks and deleting between the marks, like so:

```
:normal ma  
:call cursor(lno, 1)  
:normal mb  
:'a,'bd
```